# Date validation via dropdown

Tags: php, html, date

We all know that `<input type="date">` is not ideal for forms that require a future date to be selected.

My idea was to create a drop-down that only lists off the current date and every date for the rest of the year.

```html
<select>
<option value="Not Selected" disabled selected>Please select a date.</option>

<optgroup label="September">
<option value="1st">Sunday 1st</option>
<option value="etc">Rest of month</option>


<optgroup label="October">
<option value="1st">Tuesday 1st</option>
<option value="etc">Rest of month</option>


<optgroup label="November">
<option value="1st">Friday 1st</option>
<option value="etc">Rest of month</option>


<optgroup label="December">
<option value="1st">Sunday 1st</option>
<option value="etc">Rest of month</option>
</select>
```

This would allow me to have more control over the user input without needing to validate for a future date. Of course I could use something like php echo date for the current one but the requirements would be;

1) Get current month and add to `<optgroup label="[MONTH]">`
2) Get current date
3) Calculate dates remaining and then echo them into their own 'DD/MM/YYYY`

I don't want to have to remove the previous day's date on a daily basis and I'm not too sure how to go about generating this but I've seen date drop-downs on sites before.

The DD/MM/YYYY format would be best, they don't need to read the day of the week too, I know that's more work.

I don't have any working code because I'm not sure on the best approach. Any comments, pointers or code would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should more or less do it for you:**

```
<?php
$now = time();
$month = date('m', $now);
$day = date('j', $now);
$year = date('y', $now);
echo '<select>';
echo '<option value="Not Selected" disabled selected>Please select a date.</option>';
for ($m = $month; $m <= 12; $m++) 
{
    echo '<optgroup label="' . date("F", strtotime("$year-$m-01")) . '">';
    $startDay = $m == $month ? $day : 1;
    for ($d = $startDay; $d <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $year); $d++)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '/' . $m . '/' . $year . '</option>' . "\n";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Hero! Thank you so much for that. It just seems the best way to go about it. Is there any way of having the dropdown display the date, month and year?

Comment: Sure. I made a change. The drop down now displays d/m/y

Comment: @learningtoanimate no problem, glad I could help. Good luck on your project.